# React 18 and TypeScript Error with styled-components After Upgrading Expo from v48 to v49

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I recently upgraded my `Expo` app from version 48 to 49, and consequently updated React from version 16 to 18. After the upgrade, I am encountering a `TypeScript` error related to styled components when using components with children's props. I checked a bunch of issues related to this in SO but nothing worked for me. I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

```js
    // Row.tsx
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, ViewProps } from 'react-native';
    import styled from 'styled-components/native';
    
    interface Props extends ViewProps {
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }
    
    const StyledView = styled(View)<Props>`
      flex-direction: row;
    `;
    
    export const Row = ({ children, ...props }: Props) => {
      return <StyledView {...props}>{children}</StyledView>;
    };
    
    // MyComponent.tsx
    import React from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import { Row } from '../components/custom-components';
    
    const MyComponent = () => {
      return (
        <Row>
          <View /> <--- error appear here
        </Row>
      );
    };
```

even if I put `H1` as children it still throws this error

The error I'm getting is

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.

Dependencies:

```json
    "react-native": "0.72.6"
    "react": "18.2.0"
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.26",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "~18.0.10",
    "@types/react": "18.2.38"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when no children are passed, so change the following

```js
    <Row>
      <View />
    </Row>
```

to this

```js
    <Row>
      <View>
          <Text>Check if it works</Text
      </View>
    </Row>
```

The `Text` field is not necessarily needed, it just comes in handy to see if it works!